# Using Barba js Slick Slider not worlking

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, barbajs

I am using Barba Js for page Transitions. After initiating the barba js the Slick slider was not working. I don't understand what was the problem, how to solve this issue, any one help me to solve this issue please comment .

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider').slick({
    });
});


/* page transition begin*/

function pageTransition() {
    let tl = gsap.timeline();
    tl.to('ul.transition li', { duration: 0.6, scaleY: 1, transformOrigin: "bottom left", ease: "expo.out"});
    tl.to('ul.transition li', { duration: 0.6, scaleY: 0, transformOrigin: "bottom left", ease: "expo.in"});
}
function contentAnimation() {
    let tl = gsap.timeline();
    tl.from('body', { duration: 1.5, opacity: 0, });
    tl.to('img', { duration: 0.5, opacity: 1 },  "-=1.1")
}


function delay(n) {
    n = n || 1000;
    return new Promise(done => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            done();
        }, n);
    });
}

$(function() {
    barba.init({
        sync: true,
        transitions: [{
            async leave(data) {
                const done = this.async();
                pageTransition();
                await delay(1000);
                done();
            },
            async enter(data) {
                contentAnimation();
            },
            async once(data) {
                contentAnimation();
            }
        }]
    });
});
/* page transition end*/
```

Answer (score 0):

We Have to init and call the slider() function each time on page navigation

```js
  function playSlider(){
   $('.slider').slick({   }); 
  }


/* page transition begin*/

function pageTransition() {
    let tl = gsap.timeline();
    tl.to('ul.transition li', { duration: 0.6, scaleY: 1, transformOrigin: "bottom left", ease: "expo.out"});
    tl.to('ul.transition li', { duration: 0.6, scaleY: 0, transformOrigin: "bottom left", ease: "expo.in"});
}
function contentAnimation() {
    let tl = gsap.timeline();
    tl.from('body', { duration: 1.5, opacity: 0, });
    tl.to('img', { duration: 0.5, opacity: 1 },  "-=1.1")
}


function delay(n) {
    n = n || 1000;
    return new Promise(done => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            done();
        }, n);
    });
}

$(function() {
    barba.init({
        sync: true,
        transitions: [{
            async leave(data) {
                const done = this.async();
                pageTransition();
                await delay(1000);
                done();
            },
            async enter(data) {
                contentAnimation();
               playSlider()
            },
            async once(data) {
                contentAnimation();
                playSlider()
            }
        }]
    });
});
/* page transition end*/
```